# if (MouseDown) {}

Tags: javascript, html

I have a image (`<img onmouseover="Over(this)" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/07u0R.png">`) with the color yellow (https://i.stack.imgur.com/07u0R.png) and I want it to be able to turn orange (i.imgur.com/DPRWTbH.png) when the mouse enters the image or red (i.imgur.com/fFJxCeY.png) if it's down (pressing), just like a button.

I know I can have a variable (some people call it flag I think) that changes with the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events of the image but the problem is that that doesn't work if you release (stop pressing) the mouse outside of the browser/document/window because the variable won't change.

So, unless there's a `onmouseup` event outside of the browser/document/window, I have to check if the mouse if down on event `onmouseover` of the image.

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
var Mouse = false;
var Pressing = false;

function Body() {
  if (Mouse && Pressing) {
    document.getElementById(Pressing).src = "http://i.imgur.com/DPRWTbH.png";
  }
  Pressing = false;
}

function Down(Element) {
  Element.src = "http://i.imgur.com/fFJxCeY.png";
  Pressing = Element.id;
}

function Out(Element) {
  Element.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/07u0R.png";
  Mouse = false;
}

function Over(Element) {
  if (Pressing == Element.id) {
    Element.src = "http://i.imgur.com/fFJxCeY.png";
    Mouse = Element.id;
  } else if (Pressing == false) {
    Element.src = "http://i.imgur.com/DPRWTbH.png";
    Mouse = Element.id;
  }
}
```

```html
<body onmouseup="Body()">
  <img draggable="false" id="1" onmousedown="Down(this)" onmouseout="Out(this)" onmouseover="Over(this)" onmouseup="Up(this)" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/07u0R.png">
  <img draggable="false" id="2" onmousedown="Down(this)" onmouseout="Out(this)" onmouseover="Over(this)" onmouseup="Up(this)" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/07u0R.png">
  <br><textarea id="t"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not use CSS: `imgElement:active { color: red; }` (or `imgElement:active { background: url(path/to/image.png); }`? That way you have the functionality of you describe as missing without having to code a script to perform checks.

Comment: @DavidThomas I didn't knowed about that. How does it work exactly?

Comment: @DavidThomas, But we can not change the `src` of the image using `CSS` right ?

Comment: Where is the `Up` function declared?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker I have been testing around and at this moment is on the `<body>`. Wait, I'm gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nah, no javascript needed here.

Use css: https://jsfiddle.net/o27fcegr/

```
img {
    &:hover {
        content: url(http://i.imgur.com/DPRWTbH.png)
    }
    &:active {
        content: url(http://i.imgur.com/fFJxCeY.png)
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work as intended in a fast look up. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @MartinGottweis On a slower look I noticed that, while I'm pressing, if I move the mouse outside of the image it stays red instead of changing to yellow. I will see if I can add a if to make that. The answer is still great as I didn't asked that.

Comment: Hmm. Is the problem that you click the image, and move(drag) the mouse outside of the image while still being pressed? Would you like the image to turn back to yellow even while the mouse button is still pressed?

Comment: @MartinGottweis Yes, when I drag it out, turn yellow and when I drag back in, turn red. If you can't answer that here as it wasn't on the question or because it's locked, I can ask it in another question in about 20 mins or so.

Comment: I'll try to help find a solution for you.

Comment: @MartinGottweis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482247/while-scss-image-active-change-image-unless-mouse-out

Comment: You will probably need javascript for this one. Simply add and remove class on mouseenter and mouseleave. This is how I got it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/o27fcegr/2/

Comment: @MartinGottweis That's perfect, please put that on the new question I made so that I can mark it as solved.

Comment: no need. Glad it works for your. Let us know if you need any more help.